# See users that have spent more than X amount of time on page - GA4?

Tags: events, google-tag-manager, duration, google-analytics-4

I want to be able to see the amount of users that have spent more than 180 seconds on a page. Is this possible in GA4. I had this going in UA/GA3 as a goal

I know there is user engagement that tracks 2 or more page views + a certain amount of time (10 - 60 seconds) but I want to only track those who have spent 180 seconds or more on a page.

UA goal example I want to re-create
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ySb0BpS_W4

Leon Korteweg has a nice solution here using a custom dataLayer push.